# Code formatting for SVG does not work in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: xml, svg, intellij-idea

I have the following `SVG` file generated by inkscape.  As you can see, the formatting of the xml is quite messed up.  For one thing, in my settings I have selected "Use Tab Character", but this file contains no tab characters.  Many other things are also wrong, for example `/><g` and `><path`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   x="0px"
   y="0px"
   width="105.83467"
   height="105.83467"
   viewBox="0 0 99.220001 99.220001"
   enable-background="new 0 0 100 100"
   xml:space="preserve"
   id="svg2"
   inkscape:version="0.92.1 r15371"
   sodipodi:docname="activity_template.svg"><metadata
     id="metadata13"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
         rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /><dc:title /></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
     id="defs11" /><sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1676"
     inkscape:window-height="1117"
     id="namedview9"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="5.7699913"
     inkscape:cx="2.3719576"
     inkscape:cy="60.109287"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="298"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg2"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0" /><g
     id="Background"
     transform="translate(-0.4542549,-0.33174549)" /><g
     id="Pictograms"
     transform="translate(-0.4542549,-0.33174549)"><path
       d="M 99.167833,18.811353 81.549745,0.77689213 c -0.19,-0.19 -0.501274,-0.36095895 -0.771274,-0.36127448 L 2.1282745,0.32370588 C 1.5682749,0.32305146 0.392628,1.5090001 0.39298039,2.059 l 0.0612745,95.634902 c 3.5239e-4,0.55 1.05274521,1.857486 1.61274511,1.857843 l 96.053823,0.06128 c 0.55,3.5e-4 1.613083,-1.001471 1.612746,-1.857843 l -0.03064,-77.84554 c -1.02e-4,-0.259999 -0.345098,-0.918284 -0.535096,-1.098289 z m -4.04848,-0.222549 -13.773431,-0.06127 0.06127,-13.7347055 z M 96.937,96.939 H 3.067 V 3.059 h 75.85 v 17.02 c 0,0.55 0.45,1 1,1 h 17.02 z"
       id="path6"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccsssssssscccccccccsscc" /></g><g
     id="Guides"
     transform="translate(-0.4542549,-0.33174549)" /><path
     id="path3021"
     d="m 88.804011,52.081722 c -4.779066,-1.280811 -5.862105,-12.487045 -1.941764,-14.749867 1.285092,-0.744856 2.281658,-1.801354 2.940042,-3.019664 -1.019682,-3.718289 -4.499102,-9.07526 -6.46227,-11.457944 -1.434918,-0.06678 -2.90237,0.261128 -4.237975,1.032525 -4.276503,2.470868 -13.117176,-4.137805 -11.800407,-9.056426 0.411811,-1.536801 0.194348,-3.400653 -0.141266,-4.489685 -2.430628,-1.2568381 -8.186569,-2.9477474 -12.461359,-3.366408 -0.921224,0.6703706 -1.976009,2.2910752 -2.386965,3.83815 -1.394679,5.201152 -12.431394,5.957139 -14.798666,1.85786 -0.790233,-1.36985 -2.245699,-2.645524 -3.251684,-3.0650415 -2.765385,0.8381785 -8.774749,4.3218805 -11.205378,6.3329915 0.167807,1.424646 0.200341,3.079596 1.017115,4.492254 2.36556,4.100135 -4.04106,13.217346 -9.10009,11.862051 -1.664368,-0.445202 -3.410928,-0.318491 -4.835572,0.267977 -1.1737914,2.599291 -2.9503161,9.454537 -3.1181228,12.219923 0.3356134,0.754274 2.3364504,2.078748 3.9366088,2.506826 6.886067,1.845874 6.940006,11.944241 1.95118,14.824352 -1.409233,0.814205 -2.616414,1.944332 -3.1189784,3.369833 0.8381784,2.681482 4.2062984,8.576976 6.3852174,11.091508 1.424644,0.166951 3.079595,-0.198628 4.49311,-1.016258 4.455438,-2.574462 13.366317,3.479421 11.860337,9.101802 -0.391264,1.463171 -0.174656,3.002541 0.0762,4.511946 3.352709,1.424644 9.417722,3.42891 12.770432,3.345007 1.089031,-1.005988 1.761115,-2.407516 2.143816,-3.838154 1.318481,-4.921188 12.202801,-6.49138 14.774695,-2.035941 0.718316,1.245708 1.724299,2.428061 2.897234,3.098431 3.51966,-1.005984 9.707103,-4.468281 11.804687,-6.6472 0.08219,-1.591595 -0.517119,-2.921206 -1.261975,-4.214002 -2.77994,-4.810744 3.714008,-13.23447 9.053857,-11.802976 1.462316,0.390408 3.054767,0.258559 4.396364,-0.0762 1.172934,-2.93405 3.118121,-8.175441 3.452022,-12.533277 -1.172933,-1.340742 -2.285937,-1.970016 -3.830443,-2.384396 z m -16.2704,3.250826 C 69.274222,67.504527 56.765774,74.725351 44.595508,71.465108 32.426953,68.203151 25.206129,55.692134 28.466373,43.521011 31.726618,31.349889 44.235066,24.128208 56.40362,27.389309 c 12.169409,3.2611 19.391091,15.770404 16.129991,27.943239 z"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     style="clip-rule:evenodd;fill-rule:evenodd" /></svg>
```

So, I would like to re-format my `.svg` file, but when I do "Reformat Code" (Ctrl+Shift+L) in IntelliJ IDEA, nothing happens.

I tried going to "File Types" and re-assigning `.svg` files to the `XML` file type, no difference.

I tried renaming the `.svg` file to `.xml`, no difference.

If I do "Auto-indent Lines" (Ctrl+Alt+I) the current line is in fact properly indented with tabs, so if I do this for each line I can at least have the entire file properly indented, but no other formatting problems are fixed.

How can I have IntelliJ IDEA re-format my `.svg` file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that in this particular `.svg` file, the `<svg>` tag contains a sneaky `xml:space="preserve"` attribute.

And it turns out that IntelliJ IDEA pays attention to this attribute, so the "Reformat Code" command does nothing.

Removing this attribute allows proper re-formatting of the `.svg` file.

(So, in light of that, the fact that IntelliJ IDEA's "Indent Lines" command does not pay attention to the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute might actually be a bug.)

Apparently some `.svg` files contain this attribute, some don't, and its presence or absence does not seem to affect the `.svg` file in any other way.

**Useful comments attached to the answer for posterity:**

[ccprog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996779/ccprog) says: Inkscape adds this attribute to all text elements. It is a behaviour I have not found any possibility to change. Nonetheless, this is the first time I have seen it on the root element. You might want to look at the configuration folder of Inkscape (look at Settings -> System to find the locations for user/global configs). There are some files templates/default..svg used to initialize empty files on startup. Maybe the attribute has sneaked its way in there. You need to edit them/set a local one by hand.

[Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) says: [w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#XMLSpaceAttribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#XMLSpaceAttribute)

Comment: Inkscape adds this attribute to all text elements. It is a behaviour I have not found any possibility to change. Nonetheless, this is the first time I have seen it on the root element. You might want to look at the configuration folder of Inkscape (look at Settings -> System to find the locations for user/global configs). There are some files `templates/default.<lang>.svg` used to initialize empty files on startup. Maybe the attribute has sneaked its way in there. You need to edit them/set a local one by hand.

Comment: @ccprog thank you very much for the insights, I will look into this.